# XPath wildcards on node name

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to grab a node from my XML file, the node has a prefix such as "latest_", but this may change and I'm keen for my XSLT to be as fluid as possible. Here's the XPath I want to use:

```
/data/stats/*_cost
```

This should match `latest_cost`, `newest_cost`, `anything_cost`, is there a way of doing this?

Cheers :-)

Comment: Depends on if XPath 2.0 is available in your environment. XPath 1.0 doesn't allow this and 2.0 does.

Comment: As for expressions like `*_cost` neither XPath 1.0 nor XPath 2.0 allows them.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This is the correct XPath 1.0 expression which selects an element with the last 5 character of name equal to "_cost" in any namespace.

```
/data/stats/*[substring(name(), string-length(name()) - 4) = '_cost']
```

Comment: Fair point, I've input this into my application and it does what I need it to without the other disadvantages, see my comment to reqsquare. Thanks.

Comment: +1 and thanks to @user357812 - this has been very helpful to my similar use case (matching attribute suffixes). How to do this is [here](http://blog.jondh.me.uk/2011/10/simplexml-xpath-selector-attribute-not-having-suffix/) if anyone is interested.

Comment: I tried this: `<xsl:for-each select="substring(name(.), string-length(name(.)) - 1) = 'grp'">` I get the error: `  XPTY0020: Required item type of the context item for the child axis is node(); supplied
  value has item type xs:boolean`

Comment: For completeness, what if the user wants to search for a prefix 'cost_' instead of suffix? How would the above XPath 1.0 expression change? I'm guessing: `/data/stats/*[substring(name(), 4) = 'cost_']`

Answer (score 10):

With XPath 1.0 you can use `/data/stats/*[substring-after(name(), '_cost') = '']` pattern. That checks if the element's name ends with the `_cost` suffix.

In XPath 2.0 there is `fn:ends-with(str, str)` and your corresponding expression will be `*[ends-with(name(), '_cost')]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, contains worked well for me as it checked if the string exists as well. Also my environment doesn't appear to have XPath 2. Cheers anyway :-)

Comment: as @ILMV points out, this will select an element without "_cost" in its name. Check my answer.

Comment: [substring-after(name(), '_cost') = '']

This is also true for any name() that does not contain '_cost', -1

Answer (score 8):

You could also use `contains`

e.g

```
/data/stats[contains(.,'_cost')]
```

Comment: `.` stands for all text content and this expression will match all the `stats` nodes which text content contains `_const` substring. No guarantees about postion and node names.

Comment: I went with this in the end `[contains(local-name(),'_cost')]`, it doesn't discriminate against position which is a shame, but in the context of its use that doesn't really matter.

Comment: This is wrong. This selects a `stats` element cointaining "_cost" in its string value. Check my answer.

Answer (score 8):

The above did not work for me.  I had to "slightly" modify that as follows:

```
/data/stats/*[contains(name(),'_cost')]
```