# Loop through SimpleXML elements by wildcard query

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have a SimpleXML element, from XML like the following:

```
<Result>
    <BlueAnswer>Blue</BlueAnswer>
    <RedAnswer>Red</RedAnswer>
    <YellowAnswer>Yellow</YellowAnswer>

    <BlueQuestion>What is my favorite color?</BlueQuestion>
    <RedQuestion>What is my favorite color?</RedQuestion>
    <YellowQuestion>What is my favorite color?</YellowQuestion>
</Result>
```

How do I loop through them with a wildcard, like so:

```
foreach ($response->Result->wildcard('*Answer') as $answer) {
    echo "Answer: " . $answer;
}
```

This seems simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is [Xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) - but can't you just loop `$response->Result`?

Comment: It's more complicated than that, as there are other child elements in `$response->Result`. I've updated my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath wildcards on node name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203119/xpath-wildcards-on-node-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($response->xpath("/Result/*[substring(name(),string-length(name()) - 5) =  'Answer']") as $answer){
     echo $answer;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. Is it possible there's an error with the above code?

Comment: It works here, but if `Result` isn't the rootnode, add the correct path accordingly (or, alternatively, start it with `->xpath("//*[substring....`)

Comment: Will `//` make it relative to the query? For example, since `Result` isn't the root node, will doing `$response->Result->xpath("//*[substring...)` work?

Comment: Yes, `//` in xpaths means _'anywhere'_ , the `*` _'any name'_. However, it is costly, so if you can define it as `/rootnode/second_node/etc/Result/*`, that would be preferable.