# Using mechanize to check for div with similar but different names

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, mechanize

Currently I'm doing the following:

```
if( firstTemp == true )
    total = doc.xpath("//div[@class='pricing  condense']").text
else
    total = doc.xpath("//div[@class='pricing  ']").text
end
```

I'm wondering is there anyway that I can get mechanize to automatically fetch divs that contain the string "pricing" ?

Comment: Not exactly your question, but the closest relevant answer: use substrings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203119/xpath-wildcards-on-node-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `doc` a `Mechanize::Page`? usually the convention is `page` for those and `doc` for `Nokogiri::HTML::Document`. Anyway, for either one try:

```
doc.search('div.pricing')
```

For just the first one, use `at` instead of `search`:

```
doc.at('div.pricing')
```

Comment: It is actually a Nokogiri::HTML::Document, parsed from a Mechanize::Page. Thanks for the answer. :0

Comment: Any idea how I can access the child nodes? I used to do it doc.xpath("//div[@class='pricing  ']/input") but doc.at('div.pricing')/input doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, that would be: `doc.at('div.pricing').at('input')` or just `doc.at('div.pricing > input')`

Comment: Ok this is gonna be even more complicated. Can I like match strings with 'pricing' but discard strings like 'pricing sold' ?

Comment: Yes, that would be: `div.pricing:not([class*=sold])`, I suggest you look at the [w3c css3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) (or use xpath if you really prefer it)

Comment: @user1043625 a Mechanize::Page already exposes the page as a Nokogiri document. There's no need to parse it yourself. Make sure you're not duplicating effort.