# Xml node name Parsing using SQL

Tags: sql, xml, xml-parsing, oracle11g

I need to get the value of the tag "supervisor....." The problem is that those tag name are dynamic, they change for each person. I have tried using Extract value but it works only if you use a static tag name.

It is in Oracle environment.

Thanks for your help.

**Ourson**

```
XML Extract
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TRANSACTION>
       <TransCtx>
          <supervisorCalcAttributes classType="Ht">
             <SupervisorId10977 classType="s">Matt, Clinton</SupervisorId10977>
             <SupervisorId4753 classType="s">Bob, Sponge</SupervisorId4753>
             <FND_ENTERPRISE_ID classType="s">1</FND_ENTERPRISE_ID>
          </supervisorCalcAttributes>
       </TransCtx>
    </TRANSACTION>
```

**SQL Query**

```
select
Extractvalue( xmltype('<root>'||txndata.data_cache||'</root>'),
'root/TRANSACTION[1]/TransCtx[1]/supervisorCalcAttributes[1]/**LineItem**[1]' ) as test
from hrc_txn_data txndata, hrc_txn_header txnhe 
where txnhe.transaction_id=txndata.transaction_id
```

Comment: Who did that? Should be <supervisor id="10977" ... Do you know the id you are looking for?

Comment: It is a big system.... so impossible to modify the xml. I must find a solution to be able to get the value... their is always just 2 values and the id change for every person impossible to know the ID ;(

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath wildcards on node name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203119/xpath-wildcards-on-node-name)

Comment: I have tried but it is not working....select 
Extractvalue( xmltype('<root>'||txndata.data_cache||'</root>'),
'root/TRANSACTION[1]/TransCtx[1]/supervisorCalcAttributes[1]/*[substring(name(), string-length(name()) 10) = 'Supervisor']')

Comment: Extractvalue( xmltype('<root>'||txndata.data_cache||'</root>'),
'root/TRANSACTION[1]/TransCtx[1]/supervisorCalcAttributes[1]/Supervisor*[1]' ) as test

Comment: Result  <attr name='APP' value='bipublisher#11.1.1'/>
 <txt>java.sql.SQLException: ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00601: Invalid token in: 'root/TRANSACTION[1]/TransCtx[1]/supervisorCalcAttributes[1]/Supervisor*'

Comment: I know XPath mate, don't know Oracle though, so not going to be much help to you if Oracle function won't have it. May be close this question, try dba.stackexchange with something more specific.