# Unable to use string operations on text value of a tag, is not a valid xPath expression

Tags: xpath, wiremock

I am using string operations on xpath and getting is not a valid xPath expression.

```
{{#assign 'promoCode'}}{{xPath request.body "//*[substring-after(local-name()='commonOrderId','ABC')]"}}{{/assign}}

{{#assign 'promoCode'}}{{xPath request.body "substring-after(//*[local-name()='commonOrderId'],'ABC')"}}{{/assign}}
```

tried string operation also, none of these(substring, substring-after) worked.

Took reference of [XPath wildcards on node name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203119/xpath-wildcards-on-node-name), still no luck.

substring-after is working fine when I am validating it on any xpath tester, however, it's not working with wiremock, I am running with standalone process 2.23.2
When I looked into wiremock logs I saw Caused by: `com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathException: Can not convert #STRING to a NodeList!`. Following is the sample request xml:

```
<osn:OrderId>
               <osn:commonOrderId>ABC3534534345435</osn:commonOrderId>
            </osn:OrderId>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem here.
Did you find a solution?